# Levy distribution in C#

Tags: c#, math, normal-distribution

I implemented my own Levy distribution for a program but it seems that I get wrong values from it and after spending some time, I still cannot find where I did wrong.

This is used to generate random uniform numbers (double here) as well as the normal.

```
public class RandomProportional : Random
{
   protected override double Sample()
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(base.Sample());
    }

    public override double NextDouble()
    {
        return (double)(Sample());
    }

    public double NextStdNormal()
    {
        double d1 = NextDouble();
        double d2 = NextDouble();
        return (double)(Math.Sqrt(-2.0 * Math.Log(d1)) * Math.Sin(2.0 * Math.PI * d2));
    }
}
```

Here is how I calculate Sigma for the Levy distribution:

```
static double sigma_lev = Math.Pow(var_class.Gamma(1.0 + var_class.beta) * Math.Sin(Math.PI * var_class.beta / 2.0) / (var_class.Gamma((1.0 + var_class.beta) / 2.0) * var_class.beta * Math.Pow(2.0, (var_class.beta - 1.0) / 2.0)), 1.0 / var_class.beta);
```

Where var_class.Gamma(double x) is calculated using the code found here : [Gamma function](http://www.johndcook.com/Gamma.cs)

```
Where var_class.beta = 1.5 (all the time)
```

The actual function:

```
public static double[] levy(int n)
    {
        RandomProportional randObj = new RandomProportional();
        double[] step = new double[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            step[i] = var_class.gam * randObj.NextStdNormal() * sigma_lev / Math.Pow(Math.Abs(randObj.NextStdNormal()), 1.0 / var_class.beta);
        }
        return step;
    }
```

Where var_class.gam

```
 0.075
```

I'm using this formula for implementation:

[image: Levy]

Some examples of the results I get:

[image: Values]

From there I guess I did something wrong but still cannot find what.

Comment: Could you define the method double `var_class.Gamma(double x)` ?

Comment: @hoang It's provided in the link

Comment: What wrong values are you getting?  What value of mu are you using?

Comment: I added the image of the formula as well as some values I get from the code I gave